# Pagination not working because of two select statements

Tags: php, mysql

```
$today = date('D, d M, Y');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '$today'";
if ($_POST!="") {   
    $mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datepicker']);
    if ($mydate != "") {    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '$mydate'";    
    }       
}
$num_results_per_page = 8;
$num_page_links_per_page = 5;
$pg_param = "";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
pagination($sql, $num_results_per_page, $num_page_links_per_page, $pg_param);
if($pg_error == '')
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($pg_result) > 0)
    {
        while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($pg_result))
        { 
            echo "";
        }        
        echo "</br>". $pagination_output; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Data.";
    }
}
else
{
    echo $pg_error; 
}
```

For the above code the pagination is not working properly. I am thinking that it is because of two select statements. It will be OK if we can combine those two. Any suggestions? How can I combine those two select statements?

Pagination is working correctly for select `$today`, but not working properly for select `$mydate`. For example if the user clicks page number two in select `$mydate`, its again going to select `$today`.

pagination.php

```
$pg_error = '';
$pg_result = '';
$pagination_output = '';
$max_pages = '';
$page_id = '';
$page_numbers_per_page = '';
$pg_user_param = '';
function pagination($sql, $num_results_per_page, $num_page_links_per_page, $pg_param)
{
global $pg_error, $pg_result, $max_pages, $page_id, $page_numbers_per_page, $pg_user_param; 
$user_sql = $sql;
$page_numbers_per_page = $num_page_links_per_page;
$results_per_page = $num_results_per_page;
$pg_user_param = $pg_param; 
$all_results = mysql_query($user_sql);  
if($all_results)
{   
    if(empty($all_results))
    {
        $total_results = 0; 
    }
    else
    {
        $total_results = mysql_num_rows($all_results); 
    }
    $max_pages = ceil($total_results / $results_per_page);              
    if(isset($_GET['page_id']))
    {           
        $page_id = (int) $_GET['page_id'];          

        if($page_id > $max_pages || empty($page_id))
        {
            $page_id = 1;               
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $page_id = 1;           
    }
    $page_id_temp = ($page_id - 1) * $results_per_page;
    $sql_offset = $page_id_temp;
    $user_sql .= " limit $sql_offset, $results_per_page";       
    $pg_result = mysql_query($user_sql);
    Create_Links();     
}
else
{
    $pg_error = 'Error with the sql query you entered: '.mysql_error();
}
}
function Create_Links()
{
global $pagination_output, $max_pages, $page_id, $page_numbers_per_page, $pg_user_param;
$pg_page_name = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );

if($max_pages > 1)
{               
    if($page_id > 1)
    {           
        $first_link = '<a href="'.$pg_page_name.'?page_id=1'.$pg_user_param.'">First</a> ';
    }

    if($page_id < $max_pages)
    {           
        $last_link = '<a href="'.$pg_page_name.'?page_id='.$max_pages . $pg_user_param.'">Last</a> ';
    }
    $pre_id = $page_id - 1;
    if($pre_id != 0)
    {
        $pre_link = '<a href="'.$pg_page_name.'?page_id='.$pre_id . $pg_user_param.'">Previous</a> ';
    }       
    $next_id = $page_id + 1;
    if($next_id <= $max_pages)
    {
        $next_link = '<a href="'.$pg_page_name.'?page_id='.$next_id . $pg_user_param.'">Next</a> ';
    }

    if($page_id >= $page_numbers_per_page)
    {

        $start_point = ($page_id - $page_numbers_per_page) + 2;
    }
    else
    {           
        $start_point = 1;
    }

    $loop_num = ($start_point + $page_numbers_per_page) - 1; 
    if($loop_num > $max_pages)
    {
        $loop_num = $max_pages;
    }
    $pagination_output = '<div class="pagination"> ';
    $pagination_output .= $first_link;
    $pagination_output .= $pre_link;        
    for($i = $start_point; $i <= $loop_num; $i++)
    {
        if($i == $page_id)
        {
            $pagination_output .= '<a class="current">'.$i.'</a> ';
        }
        else
        {
            $pagination_output .= '<a href="'.$pg_page_name.'?page_id='.$i . $pg_user_param.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
        }
    }       
    $pagination_output .= $next_link;
    $pagination_output .= $last_link;       
    $pagination_output .= '</div><br />';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @saam1234 do you sending data by post-method when click page number two?

Comment: @tricolson...I think no...yes this is the problem? How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If pagination is working for "$today" then it must be the POST input value - are you making sure you're getting a proper date that mysql can understand?
the format should basically match what's in "$today".

Comment: '$mydate' pagination input is getting. But if clicks on page 2... its going again to '$today'

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that the second click is not POSTing myDate to the next page. The next page then sees nothing in POST and uses today.

To avoid this you could also check for GETs of the datepicker and then pass myDate using GET.

Edit: Clarification on updating the code to use GET
The check on mydate should be changed to something like:

```
if ($_REQUEST!="") {   
    $mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['datepicker']);
    if ($mydate != "") {    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '$mydate'";    
    }       
}
```

Which means that if the datepicker is from a GET request we still grab it.
Create_Links() should be changed to add "&datepicker=$mydate" (note that you will need to pass in $myDate to ths function.

Comment: <form method="post"><input align="center" type="hidden" id="datepicker" onChange="this.form.submit();" name="datepicker" value=""/></form>

Comment: @jim...Yes  you are correct.Second click is not posting $mydate to next page... I edited my question and added pagination.php. Please have a look. How I pass $mydate to second page?